# Is bcrypt.compare vulnerable to timing attack

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, bcrypt

In Node.js web development I saw it as a common practice to use `bcrypt` for hashing and comparison of password. Is `bcrypt.compare` vulnerable to [timing attack](https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-timing-attack-ccc-ctf/)?

Answer (score 8):

**Original post:**

It depends on the implementation of the bcrypt module you're using. bcrypt itself is just a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) and does not indicate how comparison should be done. In theory, a `bcrypt.compare` function that compared hashes with a naive string `===` comparison could leak information about the hash.

However, assuming you're referring to the most widely used [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) module for Node.js, the `bcrypt.compare` function is implemented using a timing safe [`CompareStrings`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/master/src/bcrypt_node.cc#L247) function. This function always compares all characters in the hash before breaking, which prevents it from revealing where/when the comparison failed.

**Important update:**

The bcrypt.compare function liked above is no longer timing safe, however this has been discussed in various places (for example [here](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/pull/43) and [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/720)) and the consensus seems to be that this doesn't matter because bcrypt itself is not vulnerable to timing attacks:

> One of the desired properties of a cryptographic hash function is
> preimage attack resistance, which means there is no shortcut for
> generating a message which, when hashed, produces a specific digest.